# Labeling many Raster Tiles at once

Tags: qgis, raster, labeling

I got this 42 tiles that I'm trying to show each tiles layer name on top of it like a label.

[image]

So I can know each tiles name, any Ideas on how to do that?

I have searched the web and found nothing

Comment: Usually this is done by creating polygon footprints of each raster that contains the attributes you want to label by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PyQGIS. Add all raster layers (and no other layers) to the map and execute code below. It will create centroid points for all rasters with a field holding layer name.

```py
rlyrs = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]

#Create point layer
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs={}&index=yes".format(rlyrs[0].crs().authid()), "myLayer", "memory")
provider = vl.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField("label", QVariant.String)])
vl.updateFields()

#For each raster layer create a point feature from rl extents centroid,
#populate label field with rl name.
for r in rlyrs:
    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromRect(r.extent()).centroid())
    f.setAttributes([r.name()])
    provider.addFeature(f)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

[image]